# ASP.NET MVC4 WebMatrix WebSecurity Forms authentication: Changing a username

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, security

I'm using WebMatrix WebSecurity for my application's Forms Authentication.

The user needs to be able to change his username, without being logged out.

I supposed calling WebSecurity.Logout(), followed by WebSecurity.Login() would do the trick, but Login() requires a password. Of course, I cannot provide this password as it is hashed in the DB.

How can I make this requirement work?

EDIT:
Below are a few suggestions on how to fix the issue of changing the username.

However, my actual problem was that the cookie still holds the old username. I found the following instructions on how to handle that:

http://omaralzabir.com/how_to_change_user_name_in_asp_net_2_0_membership_provider/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since WebMatrix WebSecurity is done via UserId, not Username, just change the data in the table you are storing your userdata in, and then redirect them to a new page.  You don't need to log them out and back in, I believe the new username will be picked up immediately.

Comment: I will mark this as the answer, because it solves my initial problem most accurately.

Comment: Didn't pick up the new Username for me. I added http://stackoverflow.com/a/17354255/267740

Answer (score 3):

So this is how I able to change the user name.  This all happens inside a post action method for updating all kinds of user data.

First I check to see if the user name already exists. "info" is a model object coming from the view.

```
if (WebSecurity.CurrentUserName != info.UserName && 
   this.userRepository.Find(info.UserName) != null)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "This email is already taken.");
    return View();
}
```

Then I update the database.

```
UserProfile user = this.userRepository.Find(info.UserId);
user.UserName = info.UserName;
this.userRepository.SaveUser(user);
```

Then here is the magic part.  You have to reset the authorization cookie.

```
 FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, false);
```

I hope that helps someone out there.

Comment: You're right, it is magic. Setting the Auth Cookie worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following steps

1. Get the UserDetails by UserId or UserName
2. Change the UserName
3. Now update the user data by calling the `SimpleMembershipProvider.UpdateUser`.

More details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider.updateuser%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)

Comment: This is probably the way to go, but I can't figure out how to call this method from a Controller action?

Comment: OK, there's  Membership.GetUser() and  Membership.UpdateUser(), MemberShip.UserName is a readonly property.

Comment: Sorry, the API does not allow to change the username. This can be done only via an SP. Please refer this post [middle of the page we have the sample] http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/070109-1.aspx

Comment: OK, I know how to change the username in the database. The problem is that the cookie still holds the old username...

Comment: on the response, you will just reset the cookie with the new username.

Comment: Hi thanks for the extra info, can you go more in detail on how to do that exactly?